# How to extract skills from job description using neural network

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, lstm

I am doing a project where I have to extract skills from Job Description.

I have attempted by cleaning data(not removing stopwords), applying POS tag, labelling sentences as skill/not_skill, trained data using LSTM network. But while predicting it will predict if a sentence has skill/not_skill.

Glimpse of how the data is

```
description                       skill/not_skill
Datacience and machine_learning         skill
not information extracted               not_skill
learn skill Python                        skill
```

I have read articles and research papers but I am not sure how to proceed after this. How do I extract skills.

This method I am following is from this research paper `(using Supervised approach)`. https://confusedcoders.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Job-Skills-extraction-with-LSTM-and-Word-Embeddings-Nikita-Sharma.pdf

Comment: I found multiple articles on medium related websites; I was able to find only this: https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-specific-information-extraction-from-unstructured-texts-12c5b9dceada